# PHP Closure Security problem (can modify private property outside of class), is there a way to protect yourself from this?

Tags: php, closures, access-modifiers

I was trying to modify a private property within a class without modifying the class which is of a vendor

i found a solution using [Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) in the following way

```php
class Test{
    // private or protected 
    private $secret ="My_super_secret";
    public $public = "You Are Welcome";
}

$instance = new Test();

echo $instance->public; // You Are Welcome
// echo $instance->secret; // Exception (obviously)


// but if?
$secret = (function() {
    return $this->secret;
})->call($instance);

echo $secret; // My_super_secret 

// and also

(function() {
    $this->secret = "OMG";
})->call($instance);


$secret = (function() {
    return $this->secret;
})->call($instance);

echo $secret: // OMG
```

I think the question comes naturally, **is there a way to protect yourself from this?**

### EDIT

sorry specific better the question, my goal is not to protect the information in order not to be read, but it is to prevent the writing.

the goal is to prevent the modification of information that should not be changed

Comment: You want to "protect" code running on your machine from… what exactly? `private` and `protected` attributes aren't for *security*, they're just annotations what the interface of the class looks like and how it's supposed to be used. They in no way provide any real protection from anything.

Comment: I believe that the purpose of a private or protected thing is also to prevent access to that information especially for writing from outside the class, for example in a database model the id should not change and usually only the getter is written, but doing so before saving the information I can change its id, example based on (symfony)

Comment: Agreed, it's not clear what you think the threat is here. I agree it does perhaps undermine the integrity of a class slightly if a caller can plug in a function which returns properties which are otherwise private. But ultimately...you as the programmer are in complete control of this. If you don't want to do this, don't write code which does it - similar to  (although less serious than) the general advice never to use `eval()`, really. There's no way that this can be done by a malicious user sending data to the app (unlike say, a SQL injection vulnerability), so it's really a non-issue.

Comment: `but doing so before saving the information I can change its id, example`...ok but if you knowingly do that, you'll likely get a bug, and that's entirely your fault for coding it that way. You'd have to know precisely what the consequences were, because you'd have to have studied the source code of the class you want to call the closure on, in order to know the name of the property you want to set, etc. It's all entirely in your control. Even if you give the code to others and _they_ write such closures against your class, that's _their_ fault as programmers. That's not a "security" issue.

Comment: PHP is flexible and pluggable, and closures are a feature. It's up to you how to use them (or not use them). If you don't like it, find a language which enforces the notion of `private` properties more strictly. In PHP (and most, if not all, other languages) they're not really rules, more like guidelines.

Comment: Read the duplicate for what those visibility modifiers are for. They do ***not*** lock down your code to be "unbreakable". All they do is provide indicators, which can be circumvented in all sorts of ways. You may want to look into the reflection APIs…

Comment: @ADy Pretty much all languages allow "circumventing" `protected` attributes in some way or another. It's all just code running on the CPU reading and writing to memory, and it's all in the same memory space…

Comment: @deceze that's why I didn't specify any particular language to investigate. Perhaps the OP can make their own... ;-)

Comment: thank you all for the clarity

Comment: For some perspective here: languages like Python and Javascript don't have any visibility modifiers (\* JS gained some in recent draft specs…), with the rationale being, especially in Python, that *we're all consenting adults here.* If I indicate that *this property shouldn't be touched*, usually with a naming convention like starting the name with `_`, then that's enough for other programmers to *not write code that does stupid things with this property*. That's all those things are.